# Filtering FirestoreRecyclerViewOptions with SearchView

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I've been at this all day but can't seem to figure out what's up. I'm using Firebase UI's FireStoreRecyclerAdapter to get data from the firestore and display it in a cardview in a recyclerview. But I also want to filter the search so it can say find users by name.

SearchUserAdapter.java

```
package com.example.cs4084_project_farm_market;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class SearchUserAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<UserModal, SearchUserAdapter.UserModalHolder> {

    private OnProfileClickListener listener;

    public interface OnProfileClickListener {
        void onProfileClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }

    public SearchUserAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<UserModal> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchUserAdapter.UserModalHolder holder, int position, @NonNull UserModal model) {
        holder.userName.setText(String.format("%s %s", model.getFirstName(), model.getLastName()));
        holder.userDob.setText(model.getDob());
        holder.userNumber.setText(model.getNumber());
        Picasso.get().load(model.getProfileUrl())
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.profileImage);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SearchUserAdapter.UserModalHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_search_card,
                parent, false);
        return new UserModalHolder(v);
    }

    class UserModalHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView userName;
        TextView userDob;
        TextView userNumber;
        ImageView profileImage;

        public UserModalHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_profile_name);
            userDob = itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_profile_dob);
            userNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_profile_number);
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_profile_image);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                        listener.onProfileClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

UserModal.java

```
package com.example.cs4084_project_farm_market;

public class UserModal {

    private String firstName, lastName, dob, email, address, number, profileUrl;

    public UserModal() {
    }

    public UserModal(String firstName, String lastName, String dob, String email, String address, String number, String profileUrl) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
        this.number = number;
        this.profileUrl = profileUrl;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getProfileUrl() {
        return profileUrl;
    }

    public void setProfileUrl(String profileUrl) {
        this.profileUrl = profileUrl;
    }
}
```

SearchFragment where the I set up the query through the search button in the OnCreateOptions Menu.

```
package com.example.cs4084_project_farm_market;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;


public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
    private SearchView searchView = null;
    private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener;
    private final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private final CollectionReference userRef = db.collection("users");
    private SearchUserAdapter adapter;



    public SearchFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        return mView;
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_toolbar_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Query querySearch = userRef.startAt("firstName", newText).endAt("firstName", newText+"\uf8ff").orderBy("firstName", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

                FirestoreRecyclerOptions<UserModal> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserModal>()
                        .setQuery(querySearch, UserModal.class)
                        .build();

                adapter = new SearchUserAdapter(options);
                RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

The recycler adapter then keeps getting created to store the results from what the user has typed.
I think it may be something wrong with my onStart and onStop. Should they be getting called from within the onCreateOptionsMenu? Apologies for any bad code I'm still quite new to Android Studio.

Comment: You can create the adapter with empty data and then create a the update method in the adapter to change the data in the adapter. This way you will have only one instance of adapter. 
Let me know if you need code!

Comment: Please could you show me what you mean? Thanks

Comment: OKay I am writing as answer

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to run but dry ran it. Assuming that everything is working except the refresh

Looks like you are creating adapter everytime which is not good. You can update the adapter query/options so it will refresh.

Let me know if does not work.

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
    private SearchView searchView = null;
    private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener;
    private final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private final CollectionReference userRef = db.collection("users");
    private SearchUserAdapter adapter;



    public SearchFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        return mView;
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_toolbar_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Query querySearch = userRef.orderBy("firstName").startAt(newText);

                FirestoreRecyclerOptions<UserModal> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserModal>()
                        .setQuery(querySearch, UserModal.class)
                        .build();
                if(adapter == null) {
                    adapter = new SearchUserAdapter(options);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    adapter.updateOptions(options);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(adapter  != null) adapter.startListening();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(adapter  != null) adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not it crashes when typing in a letter in the Search Field.
Console reads:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many arguments provided to startAt(). The number of arguments must be less than or equal to the number of orderBy() clauses.

Comment: Yeah, now it is issue with `querySearch` i think. Can you confirm what is the line number and is it the `Query querySearch = userRef.startAt("firstName", ...` on this line?

Comment: Yeah that's the line

Comment: You need to check your requirement on search, I updated the code you can change, you can not use multiple clause